# College assignment help (part 1 of lindenmayer system)

Tags: python

Ok so I am struggling in this computer programming class, as I am totally new to computer programming. let me post my actual assignment and then see if anyone could help get me started with it.

assignment:
This Lab is Part 1 of building a type of fractal called a Lindenmayer system.
In this first part, you will just be implementing symple set of draw commands.

Write a program that takes 3 inputs:
1) Draw String: This must be a string of draw commands (see the table below).
2) Length: This must be an integer equal greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100. It defines the length variable used in some of the draw commands.
3) Angle: This must be a floating point number equal greater than 0.0 and less than or equal to 360.0. It defines the angle variable used in some of the draw commands.

Character Draw Commands
h
Draw a straight line segment length pixels long in the current heading.
f
Same as h
g
Move, without drawing, a straight line segment length pixels long in the current heading.
+

### Turn the heading clockwise by angle.

Turn the heading counter-clockwise by angle.
A
Each of these color commands must change the turtle color to color that is different form the background and different from the other 5 color commands. Pick colors that you think look good together.
B
C
D
E
F
any other character
Ignore

So, that is the assignment, sorry it's so long. I have been reading my textbook, and unfortunately it gives very little info on how to actually do this assignment. It also didn't help that our professor showed us all these cool things fractals could do, but didn't actually tell us anything about how to do the assignment (don't ask me why?)

I am really at a loss as to how to even begin to code this thing, if someone could help me or at least point me in the right direction, at starting to go about coding for this stuff, it would really help me out. I don't expect anyone to do it all for me, just maybe help show me where to begin.

PS. There is one other thin our professor wrote that is probably important.

Now that you have the "if" statement at your command, you do need to check for bad input. If the user inputs bad data, print an error message and exit the program.

Comment: Devin, we're not making your homework for you. "Getting you started with it" would imply giving you hints or writting a chunk of code for you, which is pretty much useless, both for you, as a learning experience, and as a question on this site. We can help you if you *get stuck* or there is some *specific issue* you're having when writing your program tho. I think you should probably read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here to have an idea of how to better your question.

Comment: asermax...Look...I don't know really what your chastising me for. I specifically asked for "help" and also specifically said I didn't want anyone to "do my homework for me"...If you don't want to help me, perhaps you should just not comment. I am looking for people to give me a hand, not give me inane comments...thanks.

Comment: I'm not chastising anyone, I'm trying to enforce the usefulness of this site by pointing out the problem here. I could just given you a -1 and flagged your question, but instead I choose to give you a word about how this site works and how you could make your question more interesting for you and other people that might end up here. You obviously don't have any interest in knowing any of that nor making a useful question, so no point in trying to help you I guess.

Comment: Dude, I am new to this site. I am also totally new to programming. I am not trying to violate any rules or upset anyone's feelings. All I did was ask for help, not someone to "do my assignment for me" I tried to be more clear in following posts as to what I am having trouble with. If you want to give me a negative whatever or go around making threats to new people who are just trying to get help...then maybe you shouldn't be allowed on this site. either way if you don't want to help, don't help...I am doing the best I can, and I don't need people such as yourself making things even harder.

Comment: I seem to be unable to get my point across, but let me try once again. This is **not** the first time a question like yours has been posted around here, and even if you don't like it, it falls into the category of "do this for me plz", since there is no attemp to solve the problem and the problem is anything but specific, is just an assigment that you don't know what to do with. In any case, you would have better luck going to a site where your question would fit better, like a programming forum or something of the sort. And even if you're new, that's no excuse for not reading the rules...

Comment: Also, feel free to flag my comments if I you feel that offended by them.

Comment: asermax...I guess you have a serious case of just "not getting it" Asking for help on an assignment is VERY different then coming to this board and asking someone to do my homework for me. The fact that you can't figure out the difference is your mental malfunction...not mine. Are you the Overstack forum cop... do you have nothing better to do with your time then NOT help and only be argumentative. I really could care less what you think of my post, it is honest and not in any way against any rules I am aware of. I tried to ask for help in the best way I could. If you don't like it too bad.

Comment: *sigh* whatever you say man. The moment you resort to attacks to my person, the moment you lose the argument. Use the site as you will, hopefully your questions will be ignored and you will leave soon.

Comment: Look, as I said before, I asked for help as best I could with my limited amount of understanding of both Python, programming, and the assignment in general. And I explicitly said I wasn't asking anyone to "do my homework for me" I am not sure how you keep missing that part of the post, but apparently you do. All I asked is for someone to help get me started...that is hardly a vague question or something that you or anyone else should be upset about. I am trying my best. I am not trying to upset anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment seems simple to me so make sure you don't overthink it just because the professor showed you some strange sorcery! Yes fractals can do a lot of cool ( and complicated ) things but your professor is not asking you to do any super complex stuff. The first thing you want to do is look at the [Official Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). For this `turtle` assignment, you do not need to read all of the tutorial. Simply read the first four sections (up to the end of More Control Flow Tools) to get a good grasp on all the tools you'll need to do this assignment. I assume the main things you will need are functions and basic control flow statements so pay close attention to those parts.

The next thing you want to do is look at the [documentation for the `turtle` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html). Learn the basic commands, specifically `turtle.up()`, `turtle.down()` and how to move and rotate the turtle around on your screen. Think of your turtle as a "pen" that has an orientation and you have to tell that "pen" exactly what to do with Python commands. That should be more than enough to get you started on this assignment. Good luck to you and welcome to the world of programming. :)

Comment: Well I know enough about turtle to have it make spirals and stuff. But, I don't quite get what the assignment is asking me to do...that's the real problem. I really appreciate your help, but I disagree that the assignment is easy, it maybe for a seasoned programmer, but for a total novice...it's quite hard. I will look at the sites you recommend, but I would still appreciate a little more help with understanding just what the assignment is asking me to do. Thanks again for trying to help though:)

Comment: @Devin well then you need to be more specific as to what you need help on. Try editing your question.

Comment: Ok, so Basically I need help on understanding what the assignment is asking me to do. for instance here is a sample of what the code actually looks like: CommandString = “f-ff-fff-ffff-fffff-ffffff-fffffff-ffffffff-fffffffff-ffffffffff”
Length = 10
Angle = 90 Then here is another one:CommandString = “Aff-hh+Bff-hh+Cff-hh+Dff-hh+Eff-hh+Aff-hh++gggghhgggg+gggghh”
Length = 10
Angle = 90  So see, I have no clue what any of this stuff means or how to make it. If you have any advice on a site that might help me out I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Devin I know what the letters, length, and angle all mean just from reading your question. The letters are simply character draw commands that tell you what you're supposed to do (and in what order). Can you look at the explanation for the command strings and tell me what '+' and '-' mean?

Comment: I think the idea is to make your turtle "go forward a certain amount" and then make that become a letter in the list like "H". Then I think you need to turn the turtle like 90 degrees and make that into another letter. I think then you can do a series of "H's" and I guess "B's" which will make the turtle move and turn simply by putting in a H or B command. I am however confused as to what the + and - signs mean in the example code. And so far no one has shown us how to begin coding to change an H or B into a forward or turn command. Also I don't get the part about the "if" statement.

Comment: Hey, Shashank... I figured out that the + and - are going to turn your turtle clockwise, or counterclockwise. So I now get that that is what they mean in the example code. The problem I have is I don't know how to begin writing a code to transform the turtle commands into the letters that are listed.

Comment: @Devin You want to make a dictionary of functions. The keys of that dictionary should be the letters 'A', 'f', etc. The values of that dictionary should be your turtle functions that you define yourself. Look up Python dictionaries in the documentation.